# @import vs <link> vs monolithic css

Tags: css, httprequest

I know many similar questions have been asked but I haven't seen a comparison of all three possible methods of linking and managing styles. Which is the best and worst for browsing performance? I know that `<link>` is recommended over `@import` because it allows for parallel downloading, but I have also heard that a single large CSS is better than `<link>`ing multiple  css files. Does that mean that using `@import` is worse than one large css? I thought they would work the same way, but maybe it combines the worst of both worlds.

And then, realistically, how big of a performance difference are we talking about here? Does your typical 5-page website really need to worry about this?

So to answer this question it would be great to see some benchmarks or trustworthy estimations (ie. numbers of seconds) comparing the three different scenarios.

FOR EXAMPLE:
main.css (15kb)
special.css (60kb)
grid.css (20kb)

On a typical server, what would the performance difference be between:

- using `<link>` for all three
- using `<link>` for main.css and `@import` for the others
- combining them all into one file

Comment: Check out: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before. It's the kind of thing I'm looking for but that one doesn't deal with monolithic css.

Comment: It uses files that simulate a 2s load time, which seems pretty 'monolithic' to me.

Comment: In any case, you should be able to benchmark this yourself fairly easily, not entirely sure why you want us to do it for you... Questions like *"Does your typical 5-page website really need to worry about this?"* are purely opinion-based.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question. That is ridiculous. I am asking for hard facts here. You are putting this question on hold because of an example within the question? How do I benchmark it fairly easily? I was hoping somebody already knew the answer and this would be handy for searchers down the road.

Comment: The close reason is wrong, but... What you're asking for is roughly the same thing everyone else who has asked this question is asking for, and the reason it *keeps* getting asked is that folks don't trust the existing answers - so why is this any different? *In general*, link is better than @import and fewer requests is better than more - that's a good rule of thumb, but of course in *your specific case* other factors may apply: are some styles only needed on some pages or mediums? Can you cache a common subset more easily than the whole mess? Have you tested? Do you know *how* to test it?

Comment: The problem with *every single question asking for benchmarks* on *every single technology* that can be benchmarked is that you're probably not actually interested in what "wins" in a contrived scenario for a single pass - you need a setup close to your own that takes into account multiple iterations by multiple clients over time, and identifies both the common *and* worst-case performance. A question on how to measure or estimate *that*... Now, that'd be useful.

Comment: *"Does that mean that using @import is worse than one large css?"* The answer is 'Yes', and it's been well documented - almost to the point of common knowledge. Can you provide *specific* details on what it is you're asking? Including code samples would be ideal and would paint the picture much better, so we can address your concerns more accurately.

Comment: What existing answers am I not trusting? I couldn't find the answer otherwise I wouldn't be asking. I don't have a specific case per se. I AM interested in a contrived scenario. I don't know how to test it.

Comment: @Moss I just don't understand what you're asking that isn't covered by the link I dropped. Can you edit your post to show an example scenario? A single `<link>` to a CSS file that doesn't use `@import` is going to be the best you can do, performance-wise. Outside of that, what is it you want to know, *specifically*? If you don't have a specific case then I don't know what it is you're trying to find out, or how you expect us to figure it our for you. Please, do clarify.

Comment: "*I am asking for hard facts here*" ... *"I don't have a specific case"*... It's difficult to help you without hard facts from your end. Can you more clearly explain the scenario you want to test? FYI, your post has 3 reopen votes at the moment. Unless you can clarify, you're just going to get more answers that tell you not to use @import.

Comment: I already said, it doesn't compare one large css vs a css with `@import`. I would imagine they would take a similar amount of time but I don't know how much the additional http request adds to the time. On that page you linked to many imports seems to perform similarly to many links. They both have parallel downloads. So that would make me think that `@import` could be better than one large css in many cases.

Comment: @Moss Read [the article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) more carefully, it's right there under *"Update: April 10, 2009 1:07 PM"*. It's a fair question but I feel like you dismissed the existing evidence pretty quickly. Bottom line (again), just use a single `<link>` without `@import`. `@import` will never give you a performance boost.

Comment: Do you know how to test this? Use Firebug and open the "Network" tab.

Comment: ? Is that one long file linked separate from the 5 smaller files? There are no labels on those silly graphs. Are the green slivers the HTTP request time? If so, it seems that there is no real performance difference.

Comment: I've cast a reopen vote, hopefully someone else will be able to break it down in a way that satisfies you.

Comment: Thanks, I may end up doing a test if I have the time to figure it out. I think the answers could be useful and I suspect the performance difference is not something many web designers need to worry about.

Comment: It's not so much the server that matters, but the network. It gets more relevant when things take a while to download (bad mobile or wifi connection for example).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ben Callahan's recent talk](https://t.co/vKCTQ9LqLZ) on this very topic.

I currently import everything into one large file via SASS, because gzip can really crunch that down and 1 larger HTTP request is better than multiple, smaller requests (to a point of course).

Comment: That sounds like an awesome talk, unfortunately it isn't clear just from the slides. Does it give an answer to my question? It sounds like you are saying one large file is indeed the best. I found this question that pretty much answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831685/does-import-in-css-result-in-additional-http-requests. I didn't know if @import causes more HTTP requests. The only thing I still don't know is how big of a difference does it really make.

Comment: Yea, one file is usually the best approach. Though I'm talking about `@include` in SCSS context versus `import` via CSS. The difference is probably only noticeable if you are making multiple HTTP requests versus 1.