# What is the best way to organize CSS/JavaScript in a project

Tags: javascript, css, reorganize

I have a large legacy web project in NetBeans. The majority of the CSS files are included in the header. Some CSS are required on all (or almost all) pages and some are only on a subset of pages.

I want to reorganize at least the pages with high traffic to make sure that they don't include unused CSS. For this I will have to create multiple small CSS files to be included there (to leave only the minimum number of includes in the header). But I am afraid that if I have multiple external CSS includes it will lead to more http requests for that page, so I am not sure what is the best way to go about this. I want to improve page performance, but I do not want to reduce unused CSS and end up having too many http requests on those pages.

What would be a good solution/compromise for this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the size difference of the unused CSS really that significant?

Comment: I would start by making some measurements first.
Is the potential performance win worth the risk of introducing styling bugs?
Are you set up to test the results of your refactoring in multiple browsers?

Comment: I used http://unused-css.com/ to check what is being used/unused. It seems that a good percentage of the includes are not being used on say the main page of the website. Then there is a significant number of css includes that have over 50+% of the code unused there. So as different pages were developped, all the css was created in the same .css files instead of new ones, therefore on a lot of pages a good portion of the css is not used.

Comment: @stackunderflow I do test in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari all the time.

Comment: @Anthony I am looking for general guidelines on how to avoid this in the future, and hopefully some good pointers on how I can start fixing the current state of the project. Thanks!

Comment: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml has some good practical advice, but not about the design of your general CSS partitioning. But it will at least give you consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Its tough to do this with legacy code because you then would have to pour over it and see what is actually being used in page, not too sure of the best route to take there but for new projects there are a few ways to organize your css. First lets discuss pure css:

There isn't much of a way to get around multiple requests except for some [.htaccess trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831685/does-import-in-css-result-in-additional-http-requests) (look at the answer about .htaccess trick), so aside from that you need to break up your css in a sensible way, here is how I handle this.

Everypage gets these:

- normalize.css stylesheet
- base.css stylesheet (contains styles for default elements like form elements, headers, paragraphs and so on

Then we get more specific, I try to keep my code as modular as possible so I try to group UI compoments together like tabs and sliders and what not so then I would have

- ui.css

and finally individual sheets for sections of the site, if i have admin section there is `admin.css` for those things that are too specific for any above file

I may also have account.css or app.css for forward facing code

Now if you can use something like Less or Sass you can really optimize your code.

Because you have the power to pre-compile and you can use imports you can create less files for sections of your site/app and just import css components, an example would be like this:

admin.less

```
@import 'normalize.less';
@import 'base.less';
@import 'ui/forms.less';
@import 'ui/admin-dashboard.less';
@import 'ui/admin-update.less';
```

app.less

```
@import 'normalize.less';
@import 'base.less';
@import 'ui/forms.less';
@import 'ui/widgets/login.less';
@import 'ui/widgets/signup.less';
@import 'ui/widgets/other-widget.less';
```

And that is all these master files contain. This way when you need to make changes or add new code or a new feature you can create a new file and then just import it. You can also create as many master files as you want and only pull in exactly what is needed on each page.

This gives you great control and makes your css easy to maintain and really scalable, while also enhancing performance by allowing you to only include what is needed.

Hope this is helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is one silver bullet answer for you. You probably need to do some testing to find the best mix of the following for your use cases:

- Minimizing initial download size
- Minimizing total number of HTTP requests
- Maximizing cacheability of CSS

For example, you may have some CSS this is used on 50% of your pages.  To minimize initial download size, you may want yo keep this CSS in separate file.  However, this would increase number of HTTP requests needed to do a fresh download of page that needed it.  So if this CSS was relatively small in size, you might opt to lump it in with the main CSS, take the initial download hit, but have no need for further HTTP requests for this CSS as the user navigates around your site.

You need to do that sort of analysis do determine the best approach for your site.