# Create custom Wordpress them without style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to create a custom Wordpress them and not create the `style.css` file in the root directory of the theme? I want to completely remove `style.css` if possible.

Comment: What is the point?  At best you won't be following Wordpress Best Practices, at worst you're just creating a headache for yourself.  You have to have a stylesheet one way or the other, what is bad about it being named style.css?

Comment: What would you like to have in place of style.css? Are you wanting to just be able to have a stylesheet with a name other than style.css or are you wanting to not have a stylesheet at all?

Comment: style.css is required for the theme to be a theme, namely its header contains some essential information. You don't have to include style.css when loading the webpage or keep any actual css styles in it, but you need the file to exist.

Comment: I wanted to use SASS and have all of the stylesheets neatly organized in a folder so the root directory wasn't just a mess of files.

Comment: If you want to use SASS, you'll still need a style.css. You can however, create another directory called stylesheets (or whatever you want), and just include those in your basic style sheet. So really, you just have to include them in that main stylesheet, and never touch it again, unless you add more stylesheets in your directory. But you can't just not have that file. WordPress kind of depends on it.

Comment: @DylanHildenbrand but taking performance into consideration that creates another HTTP request doesn't it? Not that I am worried about that but I thought there may be a way around it.

Comment: I guess it does create a request per file that you include, but a solution to that might be consolidating all files into one upon deployment. This is what I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831685/does-import-in-css-result-in-additional-http-requests

Comment: I also use SCSS & sometimes compass and you can still have a separate directory for all scss files and compile them into root directory style.css without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create custom theme with out `style.css`. But it is not necessary to add your styles to `style.css`. You have to only add the header part in the style.css. It is for displaying theme name, theme url, author name, author url etc. You can create your custom theme anywhere in your themes folder. You have to only include the custom css path in `header.php`.
Below given is the only code you should keep in your `style.css` to get the theme work properly. This is the example of `Twenty Fourteen` theme. You can replace it with yours.

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: In 2014, our default theme lets you create a responsive magazine website with a sleek, modern design. Feature your favorite homepage content in either a grid or a slider. Use the three widget areas to customize your website, and change your content's layout with a full-width page template and a contributor page to show off your authors. Creating a magazine website with WordPress has never been easier.
Version: 1.2
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, green, white, light, dark, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready, accessibility-ready
Text Domain: twentyfourteen

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`style.css` is required in the root, it defines the theme name, author name and all those other things you'll see in the Dashboard.

Nobody is forcing you to add your styles to that CSS file though, you can have your own CSS files in their own folder and only include those in the `head` of your theme. You don't have to include the default `style.css` if you don't want to/if there are no styles in it.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress won't recognise any theme without a stylesheet in the themes folder. Even if empty your theme be has a style.css file. This file must be found your theme root dir.